# subprocess.run with shell=True seems to not actually run in shell

Tags: python, subprocess

```
    txt = subprocess.run(['$profile'],
    shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    print(txt.stderr)
```

I am experiencing some issues with the subprocess module. I have isolated at least one of them.
From what i understand, this code should simply type $profile into the PowerShell. This should return a path in form of a string. However, the error code I capture is the following (translated): The command "$profile" is either misspelled or couldn't be found.

Additionally, running 'dir' works, whereas running 'Get-ChildItem' returns the same error.

Could someone please explain the problem to me?

Comment: From the docs:
"On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell"

Answer (score 0):

`shell=True` is probably using `cmd.exe` as a shell, not PowerShell.

If you're looking for the profile directory of the current user,

```
os.environ["USERPROFILE"]
```

will get that on Windows.